# Bayesian modeling of 2x2 factorial design. Am I doing it right?

Tags: regression, bayesian, binomial-distribution, contrasts, pymc

I have a 2x2 factorial design with factors task (a, b) and stimulus type (c, d). I'm looking at behavioral data and was wondering how to test the main effect of task. To be more specific, I want to know if $a>b$. The data I have are counts (correct button presses), so using a binomial regression would make sense here (correct me if I'm wrong).

Essentially I thought of doing it in two different ways. One is to use a contrast to test the difference in task. For this I model each possible combination of factors, giving me four different Bionmial regression models, such as this one:

$$n_{hits,i} \sim Binomial(n_i, p_i)$$
   $$\mbox{logit}(p_i) = \alpha$$
   $$\alpha \sim N(0, 10).$$

I then end up with four posterior distributions for $\alpha$ with these combinations: ac, ad, bc, bd. I then proceed in calculating the contrast using a deterministic distribution:

$$diff = (\alpha_{ab}+\alpha_{ac})-(\alpha_{bc}+\alpha_{bd}).$$

The second way I thought of modeling it is to use a linear regression:

$$n_{hits,i} \sim Binomial(n_i, p_i)$$
   $$\mbox{logit}(p_i) = \alpha + \beta_{ab}\cdot x_{ab} + \beta_{cd}\cdot x_{cd}$$
   $$\alpha \sim N(0, 10)$$
   $$\beta_{ab} = \beta_{cd} \sim N(0, 10).$$

Now I also think there is an interaction, but before going there I want to know if I'm modeling this the right way. If looking at the main effect of task, which parameter estimates do I look at, $\beta_{ab}$? Going further, I need to calculate the difference in probability between a and b. I took the traces from the NUTS sampler and calculated the difference in probability between $\alpha + \beta_{ab}$ and $\alpha$. Or should I also include the second level: $\alpha + \beta_{ab} + \beta_{cd}$ vs $\alpha + \beta_{cd}$?

The two different approaches give me different results. The contrast approach gives me a distribution (median with 95% probability interval):

```
2.5%     0.026857
50%      0.045664
97.5%    0.064639
```

While the second approach gives me for the first difference:

```
2.5%    -0.000202
50%      0.025890
97.5%    0.051782
```

and for the second difference:

```
2.5%    -0.000140
50%      0.018837
97.5%    0.037980
```

Why do I get two different answers? Which one is right?

I'm implementing all this using pymc3, if anybody cares.

Comment: are there repeated measures in this design? or are participants randomly assigned to complete one (and only one) of four possible task/stimulus settings?

Comment: @AdamO they all perform the same task in pseudorandom assignment of when they do what task.

Comment: Then there is a repeated measures aspect to the design which you have not captured. If there is a growth or learning component to the design, the inference will be flawed. The regression you use is not linear, but logistic. It is a good probability model for the outcome. Did you constrain the $\beta$s to be equal as your notation suggests?

Comment: I struggle with the notation you're using here, but I question the validity of adding proportions in the difference you take in the first model. Also your first approach is a saturated model, hence your second model would need to include an interaction to arrive at similar predicted probabilities.

Comment: I'll have to rethink the model. You're right, it is a repeated measures design. I have a feeling I'm still missing a lot of information on how to create the model. I'll have to dig into the literature and I'll post a follow-up once I'm sure it's the right one. It will most likely end up being a multi-level model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you are not doing it right.

The logit model for probabilities that you have created with the first model is:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
& C & D \\ \hline
A & \beta_0 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 \\
B & \beta_0 + \beta_2 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \gamma
\end{array}

It is a saturated model having 4 distinct probabilities arranged by a combination of 4 different parameters. The "parameter" you've called $diff$ is 0 only if $\gamma$ is 0: $\gamma$ is a difference-in-differences describing a nonadditive effect of intervention.

The logit model for probabilities in the second model is constrained so that all effects are additive (on the log odds scale):

\begin{array}{c|cc}
& C & D \\ \hline
A & \beta_0 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 \\
B & \beta_0 + \beta_2 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 
\end{array}

Your test of $\beta_2 - \beta_1$ is a fundamentally different effect to measure.